# writing data (results) from one object method to another class/method

Tags: python, class

learning python via traditional college course and trying to complete an assignment that requires me to create a new class that writes and reads the data from another class. depending on how i format things i can get it to write 'none' or '<function class.method at 'a hex num''. if anyone could provide some assistance it would be greatly appreciated.

```
class mathClass:

    #Initialize/construct and set initial variables
    def __init__(self, num1, num2):
        self.num1 = num1
        self.num2 = num2

    #Create add method to perform basic addition
    def add(self):
        return print(self.num1, '+', self.num2, '=', self.num1 + self.num2)

    #Create subtract method to perform basic subtraction
    def subtract(self):
        return print(self.num1, '-', self.num2, '=', self.num1 - self.num2)

    #Create multiply method to perform basic multiplication
    def multiply(self):
        return print(self.num1, '*', self.num2, '=', self.num1 * self.num2)

    #Create divide method to perform basic division
    #Divide by zero exception added to the divide method
    def divide(self):
        try:
            return print(self.num1, '/', self.num2, '=', self.num1 / self.num2)
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            return print("You cannot divide by zero.")


    #Create all in one method. Previous functions are values for associated key.
    def allInOne(self):
        res = {
            "add": mathClass.add(self),
            "sub": mathClass.subtract(self),
            "mult": mathClass.multiply(self),
            "div": mathClass.divide(self)
        }

class wrfile(mathClass):

    def __init__(self, num1, num2, results):
        self.num1 = num1
        self.num2 = num2
        self.results = results
    
    def writeFile(self):
        results = str(mathClass.allInOne)
        file = open("Results.txt", "w")
        file.write(results)
        file.close()
        print("Resulsts of All In One function saved to Results.txt")
```

Comment: You need `return res` in your `allInOne` function.  You create the dict and then immediately destroy it.

Comment: By the way, `mathClass.add(self)` is the same as `self.add()`, and the latter makes a lot more sense.

Comment: thanks! this seems to have helped some but now i get the following in my results.txt file - 
{'add': None, 'sub': None, 'mult': None, 'div': None}
i know the allInOne method works as it outputs the correct results to the main program but for some reason writing from it is a different story

Comment: @PantsPants911 Your methods are returning the return value of `print()`. Since `print()` returns `None`, so do your methods.

Comment: @PantsPants911 `results = str(mathClass.allInOne)` should be `results = str(mathClass.allInOne())`

Comment: @Chris is right.  In all your method, change `return print(xxx)` to `return xxx`.

Comment: @Chris, thanks! made it work. very much appreciate the advice.

Comment: @Tim thanks! you helped a lot. really appreciate the help.